# Long delay during first query in EF - will this occur every time a new query is executed?

Tags: entity-framework

So it seems that when EF runs its first query, it has to compile the query on the fly. Subsequent calls for the query will be faster because the compiled query now resides in a cache. It also appears that the compiled query stays in cache even though my DBContexts may come and go. .(if I understand correctly)

However, will there be a delay for each query the first time each is run or will EF compile/cache all queries the first time any query is run.

And, precompilation does not look like a simple task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you query entity framework for the first time, it examines the entity model in memory and generates SQL views that will work with the database representation of that model. The larger and more complex your entity model is, the longer this will take. The only way to speed it up is to have those views generated ahead of time. It's something that IMO Entity Framework should do by default at build time, but it doesn't. Maybe some day. In the meantime you have to do it yourself.

More information can be found here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh949853

Entity Framework Power Tools lets you do this from the context menu on a dbContext derived class file.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj593170.aspx

Comment: So, if I understand the response, the first time you execute ANY EF query, the ENTIRE memory model is examined and views are compiled. So, the long delay should only occur once, regardless of the number of new queries against the model are executed.

Comment: And, EF Power Tools (which must be different than the regular EF Tools 6.1.1). was easy enough to use. I have to test it out. Will it recompile the views with Rebuild Solution or if you change the model or must you re-run Generate Views?

Comment: Yes that's correct. It builds those views and keeps them loaded so long as your app is loaded.

If your model changes, you'll need to regenerate the views again. Probably. Really it depends on how your model changes.